# How to indicate index of NSIndexSet object?

Tags: nsindexset

everyone.

I want to indicate index of `NSIndexSet` object.

Find various method but I can't find.

How to indicate index of `NSIndexSet` object?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"A", nil];

NSIndexSet *indexset = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqual:@"A"];
}];

NSLog(@"%@",[array objectsAtIndexes:indexset]);

// I want to indicate index of NSIndexSet object.
NSLog(@"%d",[indexset ?]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get number of indices stored in NSIndexSet then use count property:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[indexset count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From, iOS 4.0 and > there's few method which enumerates the `NSIndexSet`,
here's the one which answering to this question, `- (void)enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block`

```
[indexset enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%d=>%@",idx,[array objectAtIndex:idx]);
}];
```