# Replace objects in NSMutableArray contains NSMutableDictionary with NSIndexSet

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, comparison, nsdictionary, nsindexset

I've a main array (`arrayEvents`) contains list of events with fields like, start_date, event_id, event_name, many events can be possible on same date but different times. So I'm taking only unique dates (`arrayDates`) to check and compare it with the current date (`currentDate` its range from 1st day of month to last day of month) to show event on particular dates. I'm done up to here. Now my problem is that, I need to update `arrayEvents` for later comparisons so I am applying the following logic `...but I am in the middle of the sea` and don't know where to go!

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrayDates count];i++) {
    NSDate *obj = [arrayDates objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isEqualToDate:currentDate]) {
        //This date has some events, we've done up to here.
        //Now taking indexes of same objects (that's same dates objects) from the arrayEvents
        NSIndexSet *indexesOfObjects = [arrayDates indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [arrayEvents containsObject:obj];
        }];
        if([indexesOfObjects count] > 1) {
            //We found some objects into arrayEvents, now I have to update
            //those objects into arrayEvents.
            //How to achieve this?

            //My plan was to iterate each indexes and make update on arrayEvents 
            //but I can't do this, as I don't have access to each index from NSIndexSet.
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[[arrayEvents objectsAtIndexes:indexesOfObjects] 
setValue:[arrayDates objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"filter_date"];
```

isn't worked.

---

Reference, [How to indicate index of NSIndexSet object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885106/how-to-indicate-index-of-nsindexset-object) but doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[arrayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[dict setValue:[arrayDates objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"filter_date"];

[arrayEvents replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dict];
```

or you can use

```
replaceObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *) withObjects:(NSArray *)a
```

which ever suits your convenience

Comment: Y don't you enumerate from your Index set using enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:..and retrieve the respective data and then modify it and then replace it